# Entering Value in UITextField, using method from entity classes, need value to display in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm calling method doSomething in my View Controller. The method is declared in my super and sub classes (these classes are for my 3 entities - 1 is parent of other 2). The super class is called SuperClass (not really but for sake of question). I've created an instance for the class called superClass.

[superClass doSomething];

The method returns a string, this string returned is supposed to be text that is entered by the user into a UITextField declared in the ViewController. I cannot get this to work. I had it working fine when everything was contained in the VC but now I'm having to use the entity classes where if no value is returned by the superclass, it looks in the subclass. The attribute is name that is being returned.  I need to enter value in headingText (UITextField), have doSomething (method) return that value stored in superClass.name and then cell.displayText.text = superClass.name will display that value. Any and all help is super appreciated! Thanks!

SuperClass.m

```
#import "SuperClass.h"

@implementation SuperClass

@dynamic name;

-(NSString *)doSomething
{

    return self.name;
}

@end
```

SubClassA.m

```
#import "SubClassA.h"  //SubClassA.h imports SuperClass.h

@implementation SubClassA

@dynamic body;
@dynamic heading;


-(NSString *)doSomething
{
   [super doSomething];

   return self.name;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender {


    AppDelegate* appDelegate = ( AppDelegate* ) [ [UIApplication sharedApplication]      delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    SuperClass *superClass = [NSEntityDescription
                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SuperClass"
                        inManagedObjectContext:context];


   superClass.name = headingText.text; //headingText is UITextField


   NSString *fromDoSomething = [superClass doSomething];

   // I'm missing something here!

  [superClass doSomething];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0];
    }

    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SuperClass *superClass = (SuperClass *)object;
    superClass.name = superClass.doSomething;


    cell.textLabel.text = superClass.name;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: you should override [super doSomething] not [super doName];

Comment: agree with roronoa. Also why don't you redefine the getter / setter method for name instead of having a doSomething function with only purpose is to return self.name?

Comment: all the doSomething methods are actually doName in my code. This wasn't a typo in my code, just in the question posted on this forum. I probably shouldn't change the names of things for this site. There isn't both a doSomething method and a doName method in my actual code. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my final code that works. I'm passing the value (attribute "name") as a parameter.

```
- (IBAction)donePressed:(NSString*) name {

    AppDelegate* appDelegate = ( AppDelegate* ) [ [UIApplication sharedApplication]      delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    SuperClass *superClass = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SuperClass"
                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    superClass.name = headingText.text;  //headingText is UITextField on ViewController

    [superClass doSomething]; //doSomething is method in entity class

    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }



    [self fetchResults];

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or more detail for your question?

Comment: As stated above: "Here's my final code that works. I'm passing the value (attribute "name") as a parameter." StackOverflow will not allow me to mark my own answer as the answer until 24 hours have passed.

Answer (score 0):

I have not taken a look at your interface files so i don't know if you have inherited the superclass but if you have inherited and you want to override that method then you to override the method with same name as

`[super doSomething]`

how did you override doName via `[super doName]` when your methods name is `doSomething`.you should override it by

```
[super doSomething];
```

Overriding a method means that you are invoking the superclass's method with same name instead of child-class.

Comment: I apologize, all the doSomething methods are actually doName in my code. This wasn't a typo in my code, just in the question posted on this forum. I probably shouldn't change the names of things for this site. There isn't both a doSomething method and a doName method in my actual code. Thanks for the replies!